# Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, axios

I use the following technologies: 
-Java 8
-Spring (boot 2, security)
-React, axios
-Tomcat 9
-IntelijIdea

In my project I use the following http methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH and others. I have CORS configuratin. When running my project in a development environment, or when testing methods in Postman -> CORS works perfectly. However, when I collect the war file, and run it on the Tomcat server, the PATCH method refuses to work. (ERROR: method path is not allowed by access-control-allow-methods in preflight response). Please help, to fix it.

**Security configuration:**

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js",
                        "/static/**",
                        "/static/css/*",
                        "/static/js/*",
                        "/*.js",
                        "/*.json",
                        "/*.ico"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URLS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(H2_URL).permitAll()


                .anyRequest().authenticated()




        ;


        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

**CORS configuration:**

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Auth-Token","Authorization","Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Access-Control-Allow-Credentials"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you deploying into an external Tomcat if you're using modern technology for everything else?

Comment: Are you able to execute other methods except for PATCH?

Comment: What do you mean? @chrylis

Comment: @PatelRomil Other method works perfectly.

Comment: Using war files for new projects is obsolete; Spring Boot handles all that for you, and this sort of thing is exactly the kind of problem that Boot's internal support makes easier.

Comment: @chrylis It's new information for me. Can you get  more  info about it. Tt.

Comment: Hello @ЕвгенийТрахимович add below class in your project and let me know the outcome

Comment: Hello @ЕвгенийТрахимович Have you solved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

*WebConfig for CORS*. 
You can create one WebConfig Class for CORS Origin Configuration

*WebConfig.java*

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE,PATCH,HEAD");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "USERID");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "ROLE");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
      System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
      if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
          try {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Pre-flight");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,PATCH,HEAD");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
          "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                  "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you! Finally solved my CORS issue with DELETE